# CFA vs Invariance of a test different CFI

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor, scale-invariance

I am currently learning how to implement CFA and invariance of constructs between two groups. My data below has two groups. So my steps are as follows

- Confirm the overall model works
- Check if both groups have a high enough `CFI`to perform `invariance` testing
- Perform invariance testing (Configural, Metric, Scalar etc)

I originally created a CFA on a model and got a `CFI` of 0.9305597. 
When I attempted to implement `invariance` testing the `configural` step gave me a `CFI` of 0.9233984

```
model.between.groups <- measurementInvariance(model=HS.model, data = mydf, group="school", strict = TRUE)
```

For the `configural` step I got a value of 0.90 for the `CFI`

My understanding of the the `configural` step is that it just combines the groups together with no restrictions on the model. Should the `CFI` not be the same as a result?

Below is a reproducible example which you should be able to run if the `lavaan` library is installed (I apologize for the spaghetti code) The table `fit_df` contains the fit statistics

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

```
library(lavaan)
library(tidyverse)
library(semTools)

mydf <- HolzingerSwineford1939

# First Create the CFA model for both groups combined
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9'

# Fitting the model with both groups together
all.fit <- cfa(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939)
summary(all.fit, standardized= TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)

# Create Fit Indices
fit.indices <- c('chisq','df','cfi','tli','srmr','rmsea','rmsea.ci.lower','rmsea.ci.upper')
fit_df <- as.data.frame(fitmeasures(object = all.fit, fit.indices))
names(fit_df) <- 'CFA_Model'

# Split by Group to check that CFI is high enough for both groups to do invariant testing
construct.pasteur <- filter(mydf, school == 'Pasteur')
construct.gw <- filter(mydf, school == 'Grant-White')

pasteur.fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = construct.pasteur, meanstructure = TRUE)
gw.fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = construct.gw, meanstructure = TRUE)

# Specify the fit statistics
fit_df <- fit_df %>%
  cbind (as.data.frame(fitmeasures(object = pasteur.fit, fit.indices))) %>%
  cbind (as.data.frame(fitmeasures(object = gw.fit, fit.indices)))

names(fit_df) <- c('CFA_Model','pasteur.fit','gw.fit')

# Model Invariance to see if its possible to use the questionaire across groups
model.between.groups <- measurementInvariance(model=HS.model, data = mydf,  group="school", strict = TRUE)

# Add the model statistics to the summary Table
fit_df <-  fit_df %>%
  cbind(as.data.frame(fitmeasures(object = model.between.groups$fit.configural, fit.indices))) %>%
  cbind(as.data.frame(fitmeasures(object = model.between.groups$fit.loadings, fit.indices))) %>%
  cbind(as.data.frame(fitmeasures(object = model.between.groups$fit.intercepts, fit.indices))) %>%
  cbind(as.data.frame(fitmeasures(object = model.between.groups$fit.residuals, fit.indices)))      

names(fit_df) <-  c('CFA_Model','pasteur.fit','gw.fit','configural','loadings','intercepts','residuals')

View(fit_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you assume that the configural step should get the same CFI result as the model with no grouping? They are not the same. The latter estimates simply one parameter and ignores any grouping while the former lets them vary by group. So naturally, you'll get somewhat different results.